# Does putting queries within loops cause an issue on Wordpress?

Tags: wp-query, loop

If I include a new wp_query within another query's loop (e.g. putting even a very simple query, like the ones from the codex example on a single page template) the page loads as expected, but the title changes to "waiting for..." plus whatever the page name is.

The page loads in a good time, but the title thing is worrying me - why is this happening, and could it be causing a memory leak?

Comment: Without your code, it is difficult to tell. What exactly are you trying to do

Comment: That sounds to me like there is a filter on `the_title` or something about how title strings are concatenated may be messing things up, but as Pieter said, without the code it is going to be hard to answer.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no issue you can use query inside a loop with the help of reset post data and query

- `wp_reset_query()` - ensure that the main query has been reset to the original main query
- `wp_reset_postdata()` - ensures that the global $post has been restored to the current post in the main query.